# How can i switch schema in Spring dataSource bean

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, spring-mvc, datasource

im using Oracle database

its my bean:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
        <beans:property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:x"/>
        <beans:property name="x" value="x"/>
        <beans:property name="x" value="xx"/>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

id like to change current schema using spring. in sql query looks like:

ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA = name .

can i set some initial query or some parameters? how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
      ......................
     <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schemaName?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"/>
      ......................

</bean>
```

change the schemaName as your wish. :)

Comment: its not working like this for oracle. <beans:property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL"/> i have there SID